# How to setup Alfresco SDK for Android with Android Studio 3.1.3?

Tags: android, alfresco

I want to make an Android application which should be accessed with Alfresco login credentials and should have Alfresco at back-end side. I'm using Android Studio 3.1.3. When I try to import Alfresco SDK in Android studio it does not allow me to do so and shows me the following screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it will not allow to install here.
 you must have to install in c:user/admin/

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: specify a directroy to the android studio